# Intermittent, successful reads between .Net application on Windows 2008 to an Isilon over SMB2 taking 30 seconds

Tags: windows, .net, server-message-block

We have a .Net 2.0 application that reads files off an Isilon share using SMB2.  Normally, we have sub-second performance.  Between 0 and 2% of the requests, take 30 seconds.  The problem appears to get worse with load(reaches 2% of requests).  We appear to be hitting a timeout, but the application just does a check for file existence and then a read without ever receiving an error (the actions are successful).

We suspect the problem is within the Windows machine due to some odd, but similar problems with a Sparc based Samba share that we were never able to isolate.

At the moment, we are trying to capture a delay with a network trace and convince ourselves that the problem is in the Windows environment, or the VMWare instance the contains it.

Are there any known timeouts within the Windows stack that we identify that might explain a 30 second timeout, but a successful completion of the IO request?

Comment: Did you ever find anything out about this problem?  We're seeing a similar problem in the field.

Comment: We replaced the NAS with another solution(we had other issues). Another user contacted me with the same problem. They did track it to an Isilon performance setting. I remember it being related to an optimistic lock, but I don't think I was ever told the setting name.